# Add the button at the bottom of UICollectionview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionview

I have a problem: I want to 1 button at the bottom of the UICollectionview to allow user select all photos. That button is the Select All button, when scrolling that button always at the bottom of the collectionview. When I click on that button, all photos in collection view will be checked. I tried add the footer but that is not what I want. I dont know how to add that button. Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: include the image:

You can see the image at here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51Rba.png)

The "Select All"button at the bottom of the collectionview. That button will be appeared after the user long press 5seconds. If user click on this button, all photos will be seleted. How can i do that?

Comment: can you please explain it in details or can provide sample code or application screen shots?

Comment: You can try adding another section which contains only one item with a button.

Comment: @user3884889 upload an image bro, an clearly explain your query.

Comment: add your button on self.view as a subview , and use bringsubviewtofrontview for displaying your button on above all the view.

Comment: Hi , i also facing same problem . i added a button below UICollectionView .But it is not visible when iPhone is in portrait mode . But button is visible in Landscape mode .

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you should just add a UIButton below the collection view and make the collection view's frame shorter. This way you will be able to have that buttons action manipulate the collection view and will always be in sight at the bottom

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,50)];
[self.contentView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: I want to add this button in front of the uicollectionview. You can please check my edit? Thanks

Comment: yea just add that button in front of the collection view, it doesnt have to be a part of that collection view. add both to the view independantly

Comment: I dont know how to bring that button in front of the collectionview. Can you give some example code? Thanks.

Comment: are you using the interface builder or doing this all programatically ? Just do something like

Comment: I'm doing all programatically. I write a custom class for uicollectionview to use it for many viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,50)];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

if you want bring view to front, you can chooses some API.

```
bringSubviewToFront:
```

Moves the specified subview so that it appears on top of its siblings.

```
sendSubviewToBack:
```

Moves the specified subview so that it appears behind its siblings.

```
insertSubview:atIndex:
```

Inserts a subview at the specified index.

```
insertSubview:aboveSubview:
```

Inserts a view above another view in the view hierarchy.

More detail, [flow Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want select all button always to be at the bottom then you should add it to the view and make sure to add button after adding the collectionview and it will always be at the bottom.

You can add long press gesture on a collection view like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // attach long press gesture to collectionView
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr
    = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = .5; //seconds
    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}

-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        return;
    }
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil){
        NSLog(@"couldn't find index path");
    } else {
        UIButton *btnSelectAll = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnSelectAll.frame = CGRectMake(110,437,100,30);
        [[btnSelectAll titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18]];
        [btnSelectAll setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnSelectAll addTarget:self action:@selector(selectAllEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btnSelectAll];
    }
}

-(IBAction)selectAllEvent:(id)sender{

    //Write code to select all images

}
```

and don't forget to remove the button from its superview after you done with it. I think this will help.

Comment: Your code worked fine. But how to add that button at the bottom of the UICollectionview. I  tried your code but it can not add at the bottom screen when I scroll. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: try setting background color or something the button will get visible.

Comment: Yes, the button is shown but its location is not correct. How can i add it always at the bottom in the collectionview

Comment: Set button frame accordingly CGRectMake(110,437,100,30); Whats the big deal in it?

Comment: The issue is the button is not shown at the bottom when I scroll the collectionview.

Comment: I added the button on the collectionview. So when i scroll, it is invisible. How to make it always visible when scrolling the collectionview?

Comment: Thats what I am trying to say don't add it on your UICollectionView add it to the view.